# Manipular retorno JSON com Javascript e codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Tenho uma consulta JSON que me retorna um array de dados de usuarios.Não estou sabendo listar isso na tela, quando digito uma parte do nome do usuario aparece tudo junto, não dando a opção de eu selecionar.

Model.php

```
 function toJSON()
{
    $return_arr = array();
    $this->db->select('idusuario, cpf, nome');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    $this->db->where("situacao = 'ATIVO' AND nome like '%" . $_GET['term']. "%'");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0) {
       foreach ($result as $row) {              
           $row_array[] = ($row->nome) . " | " . $row->cpf . " | " .$row->idusuario;
           array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
        }
    }        
    return json_encode($row_array);
}
```

controller.php

```
public function index()
{
    {
        $this->load->model('loginModel');
        $result = $this->loginModel->toJSON();
        $dados = array($result);
        echo json_encode($dados);
    }
}
```

Javascript na pagina que recebe os dados

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //Usuarios
    $(function () {
        $("#codigouser").autocomplete({
            source: "../loginController/index",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#codigouser').val(ui.item.codigo);
                $('#nome').val(ui.item.nome);
                $('#cpf').val(ui.item.cpf);
                $('#matricula').val(ui.item.idusuario);

            }
        });
    });
```

Como aparece quando digito o nome ou parte dele, seleciona todos os campos e veem todos juntos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que estás a fazer json_encode duas vezes. No index apenas tens de retornar o resultado que vem do model.

```
$result = $this->loginModel->toJSON();
echo $result;
```

No SQL apenas retorna 3 campos e você está a preencher 4. Se conseguir adicionar o campo pode preencher os inputs fazendo um split do seguinte modo:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var campos = ui.item.value.split(" | ");
    $('#codigouser').val(campos[0]);
    $('#nome').val(campos[1]);
    $('#cpf').val(campos[2]);
    $('#matricula').val(campos[3]);
}
```

Comment: Apareceu da maneira certa, mas quando clico em cima ele ainda não preenche os campos, é como se as variáveis não venham.

Comment: Editei a resposta.